Unable to create fulltext search in neo4J dB
I am trying to create a fulltext search in Neo4J. I was using
this article as a guide https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2019/01/11/neo4j-full-text-search-deep-dive.html.  However, when I run the command to create index, it returns an error saying "Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound".
Trying to see if I have the right permissions using SHOW ROLES command returns an error saying "Neo.ClientError.Statement.UnsupportedAdministrationCommand".  I used the default neo4j user to login.  I am not sure what I have to do to grand this user the right access.  Thanks for your help.

Which version of Neo4j are you using?
If you are using Neo4j 5.x, then there is a different command (not a procedure) to create a fulltext index:
https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/indexes/semantic-indexes/full-text-indexes/
As for the error when you tried to run SHOW ROLES, that is only available in Neo4j Enterprise Edition. If you are using Community Edition, then that command (among others) will not be available to you.
In the documentation for a feature if you see an "Enterprise Edition" tag near the title, then it may be restricted in full or in part.
